# Django+Appengine - Development workflow when storing to GCS

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing a Django app in Appengine, a function of it is to upload a file from the user to Google Cloud Storage in my app. When deployed to production, it works well and the file is uploaded without any issue.

But I need to work on it in my Dev environment as well. I have a `DEBUG` variable which indicated the environment. So I need to upload the file and store it somewhere in my local directory, when using the Development server. But the AppEngine sandbox prevents the use of the 'open()' system call, so I can't really write any file on my local disk when in the dev environment.

What is the common solution to this? I could simply not write the file anywhere at all in the dev environment, but I need to read this file at various later stages in the web app.

Comment: Are you using the new [cloudstorage gcs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted) library? If so, it writes to a fake local area when under the dev environment.